# PHP Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php

I have had a search around on this but the answers I could find only provide more detailed error reports - I know why the error exists I am trying to prevent the error happening!

My code is:

```html
$player_sql = "SELECT player FROM player_instruments WHERE instrument = '".$instrument_id."'" . $users_helping;
$result = $db->query($player_sql) or trigger_error($db->error);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
 $position_where .= $row['player'] .",";
 }
```

Now when there are results this problem produces no error, but with no results from the query I receive the error:

> PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object

This is because the statement $result->num_rows has no results, unfortunately this is what this line of code is supposed to be checking!

So long and short of it, how do I verify if results exists without this error coming up when there aren't any results?

Comment: Query returns false, you have error in there. What is in the `$users_helping` var?

Comment: $result may be a boolean? check that quick

Comment: I found the solution, it was in the variable $users_helping. This was producing a value of "AND IN()" which was in turn causing the error to then come up. Fixing this so it produced "AND IN(0) instead meant that no errors were produced. Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

Check if $result is an object

```
if (is_object($result) && $result->num_rows > 0) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Spent an hour or two trying to figure this one out, and on many different sites.

I will lay it out in practical terms. There are 2 ways to json_decode. Depending on which you use changes how you should respond to it later in code.

```
1:    $Response_decode1 = json_decode($response1, TRUE);

2:    $Response_decode2 = json_decode($response2);
```

Option 1 makes the response $Response_decode1 act like a native PHP array callable by name. 
eg use square brackets (in PHP) when calling children.

```
1: $Response_decode1['level1']['level2']
```

Option 2 makes the response $Response_decode2 act like a responding object with (children) objects called by name

```
2: $Response_decode2->level1->level2
```

EG
    Type 1

```
 foreach ($Response_decode1['level1']['level2']['level3'] as $entry){
        $TelNo .= $entry['value'];
        $TelNo .= " / ";
    }
```

EG
    Type 2

```
foreach ($Response_decode2->level1->level2->level3 as $entry){
        $TelNo .= $entry->value;
        $TelNo .= " / ";
    }
```

I trust this helps